# Erro tentando acessar um elemento do array

Tags: c, array, tipagem

Como faço para que a execução do meu *loop* gere um código do cadastro automaticamente?

> Erro na linha 36 - 'livro[i].cod = i;' [Error] subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector

Objetivo desde código: cadastrar 5 livros com informações dos mesmo e gerar um código automaticamente para cada livro gerado.

Código atual:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*Definindo tamanho*/
#define TAM 5


int main(void) {


    /*--Criando a struct--*/
    struct ficha_do_livro {
        int cod;
        char nome_da_obra[50];
        char nome_do_autor[50];
        char nome_da_editora[50];
    }livro;


    /*--Cadastro do Livro--*/
    int i; 

    for (i = 0; i < TAM; i++) {

        printf("\n---------- Cadastro dos Livros -----------\n\n\n");

        livro[i].cod = i;
        printf("Insira o nome da Obra: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(livro.nome_da_obra, 40, stdin);

        printf("Insira o nome do autor: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(livro.nome_do_autor, 40, stdin);

        printf("Insira o nome da Editora: ");
        fflush(stdin);
        fgets(livro.nome_da_editora, 40, stdin);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa usar um array de estruturas.
Obs. não testado.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/*Definindo tamanho*/
#define TAM 5

int main(void)
{

  /*--Criando a struct--*/
  struct ficha_do_livro
  {
    int cod;
    char nome_da_obra[50];
    char nome_do_autor[50];
    char nome_da_editora[50];
  } livro[TAM]; // <-----------------------

  /*--Cadastro do Livro--*/
  int i; 

  for (i = 0; i < TAM; i++)
  {
    printf("\n---------- Cadastro dos Livros -----------\n\n\n");

    livro[i].cod = i;
    printf("Insira o nome da Obra: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(livro[i].nome_da_obra, 40, stdin); // <---------------

    printf("Insira o nome do autor: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(livro[i].nome_do_autor, 40, stdin); // <-----------------------

    printf("Insira o nome da Editora: ");
    fflush(stdin);
    fgets(livro[i].nome_da_editora, 40, stdin); // <---------------------

  }
}
```

Comment: Vlw a todos, vc me mostrou onde estava os erros de sintaxe, mas não entendi o por que de ser stdin no fgets e não stdio...

Answer (score 3):

Tam alguns erros no código. Este que aparece é que está tentando acessar um elemento de um *array* em algo que não é um *array*. Você declarou uma estrutura, e uma variável com o tipo dela, mas ali só cabe um único elemento. Se você quer colocar vários elementos precisa colocar na sintaxe que quer isto, indicando quanto elementos esta variável terá. Aí este erro desaparecerá. Mas dará outros erros já que os outros membros da `struct` depois do código também precisam ser acessados pelo índice do *array*, então falou colocar o `i` lá também.

Preste bastante atenção porque retirei um monte de coisas que não eram necessárias neste código, e arrumei algumas coisas que o deixa mais eficiente. Sim, até o comentário não é necessário porque ele diz uma obviedade, comentários não foram feitos para isso. Não use coisas que não sabe para que serve.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define TAM 5

int main(void) {
    struct {
        int cod;
        char nome_da_obra[41];
        char nome_do_autor[41];
        char nome_da_editora[41];
    } livros[TAM];
    for (int i = 0; i < TAM; i++) {
        printf("\n---------- Cadastro dos Livros -----------\n");
        livro[i].cod = i;
        printf("Insira o nome da Obra: ");
        fgets(livro[i].nome_da_obra, 40, stdin);
        printf("Insira o nome do autor: ");
        fgets(livro[i].nome_do_autor, 40, stdin);
        printf("Insira o nome da Editora: ");
        fgets(livro[i].nome_da_editora, 40, stdin);
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/cpDQRu). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/AccessArray). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Array/AcessArray.c).

Comment: Esse é apenas o inicio de um projeto não o mesmo completo, ainda vou colocar mais coisas por isso ainda esta em alpha. vlw pela atenção

Comment: E o que isso quer dizer?

Comment: Você escreveu uma perguntar muito vaga, "E o que isso quer dizer?" não especifica o contexto do seu comentário referente ao meu, especificadamente quis dizer que não é um projeto objetivo, com foco em escopo e eficiência do mesmo sendo sua estruturação atual focada em um desenvolvimento de teste e aprendizado, a estruturação do comentário no mesmo é para em futuro próximo ter fácil entendimento do escopo do próprio algoritmo.

Comment: Seu comentário é muito vago, eu dei uma resposta, você comentou algo que não parece ter significado algum. O contexto do meu comentário é o seu comentário sem contexto. Eu não falei nada sobre o contexto do seu projeto ou o que você quer fazer com ele. Eu falei qual o erro que você cometeu e que tem um monte de coisas desnecessárias nele, e agora que você dá alguma contexto posso dizer que coisas desnecessárias são ruins para o aprendizado.

Comment: Quando usa o que não precisa, aprende errado, e eu odeio quando as pessoas aprendem errado, por isso sempre ajudo em tudo o que posso, não apenas consertando o erro apresentado, porque isso não ensina. Eu costumo dizer "funcionar é diferente de estar certo". Se pesquisar aqui encontrará isso e ilustração de como é o software da maioria das pessoas quando elas não se preocupam em fazer certo. Eu percebi que você teve o problema resolvido, mas não entendeu a solução, por isso coloquei na resposta descrição do erro e o que eu corrigi, mas parece que você não valorizou isso.

Comment: Nem todos sabem como estrutura todos tipos de códigos, se estou aqui é porque estou para tirar minhas duvidas e aprender com as mesmas, agradeço que goste de ajudar, mas compreenda que nem toda forma de aprendizado se dar na explicação dos erros mas também quando nos os cometemos e os corrigimos para assim aprender com os mesmos. O aprendizado não se da apenas de uma boa estruturação semântica do código o tornado 'eficiente', mas também de errar e reconhecer que nunca saberá o suficiente sobre tal assunto.

Comment: É um direito seu acreditar nessa falácia.