# "Warning comparison between pointer and integer" - o que é?

Tags: c, tipagem, comparação

durante a compilação do código em linguagem C me apareceu este erro:

> [Warning] comparison between pointer and integer

em relação a esta etapa do código:

```
    if(livro > TAM) {
        printf("------- Você já cadastrou o maximo de livros ! -------");
    }
```

Sendo `livro` uma `struct`:

```
struct fichaLivro {
    int cod;
    char obra[50];
    char autor[50];
    char editora[50];
}livro[TAM];
```

e `TAM` uma constante:

```
#define TAM 5
```

O que esta acontecendo e como posso solucionar o mesmo?

Comment: Não entendi a lógica adotada. Você tem um loop onde varia o índice de 0 até o máximo possível de se colocar no array, no  caso TAM-1, então é óbvio que ao final do loop você cadastrou o máximo de livros, seu teste não tem sentido.

Comment: O teste é para informar se foi cadastrado o máximo de livros, como defini o valor da array máximo da array de 5 sempre sera cadastrado o máximo, mas como o usuário ira saber se foi cadastrado caso tente cadastrar mais livros?
Inicialmente pensei em comparar a array direto com o tamanho dela, mas como o Maniero informou em C a tipagem é estática, de forma leiga não da para comparar 'casa' com 'barco', então comparei um dos elementos da array que sempre sera 5 itens com a constante para informar se já tem o máximo de livros cadastrados.

Comment: Deixe eu tentar explicar. Ao final do loop a variável i, que é a variável que deveria estar sendo testada no if (if (i > TAM)), sempre estará com o valor TAM, já que em nenhum ponto do loop você interrompe o loop, ele sempre irá até o final (a condição i<TAM do comando for). Dessa maneira seu teste é inócuo pois sempre terão sido cadastrados o máximo de livros possível e sua variável i nunca será maior que TAM, será igual.

Comment: Entendi, mas como eu faria para mostrar que ela esta preenchida? (desculpe minha ignorância não sou programador em C)

Comment: Cara, você não implementou a opção de preencher parcialmente apenas pode preencher totalmente!

Comment: Agora entendi, obrigado pela ajuda.

Answer (score 4):

O erro é exatamente o que está escrito, como você declarou a variável `livro` como um *array*, ela se torna um ponteiro para uma sequência de dados, já `TAM` é uma constante numérica.

C é uma linguagem de tipagem estática, porém fraca, então ela até deixa fazer comparações mesmo que não faça sentido, em um ponteiro e um número simples são duas coisas completamente diferente é como você querer saber se uma maçã e um cavalo são a mesma coisa, não dá nem pra começar comparar, então a maioria dos compiladores avisam que isto produzirá um resultado sem sentido. A solução é comparar coisas que fazem sentido, mas nem sabemos exatamente o que faria sentido aí, o que está tentando comparar, a única coisa certa é que um livro pode ser comparado com um 5.

Olhando o código todo em [outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/394438/101) talvez queira comparar o `id` do livro, algo assim:

```
if (livro.id > TAM) {
```

Mas aí livro teria que ter só um livro e não um *array* de livros (o que alias a variável deveria chamar `livros` e não `livro`.

Se realmente vai trabalhar com o *array*, talvez esteja dentro de um laço e queira fazer algo assim:

```
if (livro[i].id > TAM) {
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/Member.c).

Mas se estiver um laço talvez queria fazer `if (i > TAM) {`.

Mas pode ser que todas opções estejam erradas porque o conceito é errado e nem deveria fazer isto.

Depois da edição vê-se que o problema nem deveria existir. O código já está rodando para cadastrar o tamanho máximo, nem permite cadastrar menos que o máximo, nem mais, então esse `if` todo não faz sentido, mesmo que crie um controle, que é a terceira opção que eu havia dado acima, ele nunca entrará nesse `if`, então é só tirá-lo.

Eu nem vou tentar mostrar outra forma de fazer isso melhor porque eu já sei que prefere fazer do seu jeito, mesmo ele não sendo bom.

Comment: eu estudei um pouco e consegui algum progresso no percudo do código, irei atualizar o mesmo para melhor compreensão, agradeço a ajuda.